# Merge data from one sheet to another based on criteria and only populate specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge, append, criteria

I have two data sources I wish to combine.

**Sheet 1**

Data source on Sheet1 contains 2 columns: AccountID and Cost. Source is in cells A3:B3 (data row starts in A4) for 1 to N records. A secondary cell contains the year value for all records to be used in this source. It is in cell D1.

**Sheet 2**

Data source on Sheet2 contains 6 columns and in range A1:F1 (data starts on row 2): Year, AccountID, Location, Phone#, Email type, & Cost. Data continues for 1 to N records.

I wish to join the records of both tables based on the AccountID of each range of data (Sheet1 column A, Sheet2 column B), where the year (sourced on Sheet1!D1) is added to all records on the Sheet2 data, and records matching by AccountID. The data is appended /added to Sheet2 on last available row.

**Example #1**

AccountID "1234" is on Sheet1 but not on Sheet2. Year value (Sheet1!D1) contains 2020. The end result would have a new row added with the AccountID of "1234" into Sheet2, the associated Cost value, and a year of 2020.

**Example #2**

AccountID "1234" is on sheet1 and also on Sheet2. The record on Sheet2 has a year value of 2019. The record on Sheet1 has the year 2020 associated with it (Sheet1!D1 cell value). The end result would have two rows of data for AccountID of "1234" in Sheet2, one for the 2019 record and one for 2020 record, as found on Sheet1 data source. The latter would not include Location, Phone#, or Email type values as they are not specified

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dROT7.jpg)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nWjd.jpg)

[Sheet2 once Sheet1 data is appended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTGbv.jpg)

Comment: David, there is no free code writing service here. If you wrote code and have a problem with it please re-phrase your question around that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Set rng_ID = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B") 'set ID range on sheet2
oYear = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value 'get year value on sheet1
Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").End(xlDown)) 'set ID range on sheet1

With Sheets("Sheet2")
For Each cell In Rng 'loop to each cell in ID range on sheet1
oCost = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'set the cost value
Set c = rng_ID.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) 'find if the cell value is in ID range on sheet2
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 'if found
    Set xCopy = .Range(c, c.Offset(0, 4)) 'set the range found to be copied
    c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert 'insert entire row below the found cell
    xCopy.Copy Destination:=c.Offset(1, 0) 'copy the range above then paste
    c.Offset(1, -1).Value = oYear 'fill the year
    c.Offset(1, 4).Value = oCost 'file the cost
    Else 'if not found
    Set oFill = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B500000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'set the last blank cell in column B sheet2
    oFill.Offset(0, -1).Value = oYear 'fil the year
    oFill.Offset(0, 4).Value = oCost 'fill the cost
    oFill.Value = cell.Value 'fill the ID
    End If
Next cell
End With

'unmark the line below which one you want     
'Call SortByYearThenByID
'Call SortByIDThenByYear
End sub
```

I try to add it with a sort code, maybe the result as you want it

```
Sub SortByYearThenByID()
Set rngSort = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Range("F1").End(xlDown))

Sheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        rngSort.Sort Key1:=rngSort.Columns(1), Key2:=rngSort.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=yes
End Sub

Sub SortByIDThenByYear()
Set rngSort = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", Range("F1").End(xlDown))
Sheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        rngSort.Sort Key1:=rngSort.Columns(2), Key2:=rngSort.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=yes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Karma! it works. Only challenge i see is that in line **c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert 'insert entire row below the found cell** it replaces the record that already exists within sheet2. For example, if sheet2 has 2 records of an AccountID, this line i am assuming finds the first record in first row and then overwrites the second row.. If you can assist me how to avoid that that would be great. Otherwise i will search around for a solution. Thank you again!

Comment: @DavidD, do you mean that in Sheet2 column ID, there is a possibility that there are two or more of the same ID ? If yes, then on which ID you want to insert the new year and cost ? the first ? the second ? the third ? and so on (depends how many same ID there)

Comment: Yes. i added Shift:-xlDown after that line of code, and it is currently running. hopefully it does the job. Thank you again for your prompt response. I would prefer it to add to the latest Year which is added to Column A. So if year 2019 already exists for that accountID, then the new row i am adding underneath is added After year 2019.

Comment: @DavidID, you wrote "this line i am assuming finds the first record in first row and then overwrites the second row" ... I don't understand it, because in my side, it does not overwrite the row below the found cell, but shift the row below the found cell to the next row. The line c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert is to insert a blank row right under the found cell while all the rows below the found cell before will be shifted to the next row. BTW, I add the sort code. Maybe you can try it and hopefully the result is as you expected.

Comment: Sorry it was an error on my end with adding a row. I changed the Offset(1,0) to Offset(5,0) so was showing odd results. Thank you again for the sort function its tremendously helpful!

Comment: @DavidD, glad I can help. You're welcome and thanks too.